# How to display interactive plots while using Jupyter Lab on R Studio Workbench?

Tags: python, rstudio, bokeh, jupyter-lab, rstudio-server

**Description**: I am using Jupyter Lab on R Studio Workbench. I wrote a python code using the Bokeh library to display some graphs.

When I run the code, it perfectly renders the graph with all its sliders and dropdowns, however there is no active interaction. As a matter of fact I get the following worning:

```
WARNING:bokeh.embed.util:
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.

Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more
information on JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh, see:

    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Alternatively, to use real Python callbacks, a Bokeh server application may
be used. For more information on building and running Bokeh applications, see:

    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html
```

One solution to make it work on my local computer would be creating a local Bokeh server by using the following line of code:

```
bokeh serve --show name_of_file.ipynb
```

However when I run this line of code on the terminal in Jupyter Lab nothing happens. I would expect some browser tab to open and render my interactive plot.

**Question**: Are you aware of any possible way to display interactive plots while using Jupyter Lab on R Studio Workbench?

Comment: I don't know about R Studio Workbench; however, a while ago I helped [someone with a coding question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59610286/8508004) and they were using Bokeh plots. At that time, I was only concerned with classic notebook. Now by adding the `jupyter_bokeh` extension, I see they work **interactively** in JupyterLab. You can go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila) & look at the two Bokeh examples listed under 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode in Jupyterlab’s single document mode'. You could test your code maybe in the launched session.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for the hint but I had already tried and nothing happened unfortunately.

Comment: Darn. Depending on the size of your data, you could use MyBinder-served launched sessions from that second link to work on stuff.

Comment: @Yeah I saw that yesterday but I am afraid to use it since it has private data which is not supposed be shared except with the company that I work for. I think I will use a VM and run the server from there

Comment: Oh yes, that would certainly be a concern.